# Is it possible to appeal a refused Schengen visa? (Germany short stay holiday visa was refused)

Tags: visas, schengen, legal, germany, paperwork

I am from Sri Lanka and applied for a short stay holiday visa to Germany for two weeks from 30th Dec 2013 to 11th Jan 2014 with my two children age eight and ten. My husband did not apply due to his leave not being approved by his company.

But my visa application was refused and the reason mentioned was "your intention to leave the teritory of the member states could not be ascertained".

Can I appeal against that? And what documents would I need to appeal? I already gave my proof of my properties, company letter, our tax file, business registration, funding deatails etc.

Comment: I changed the title for you since the appeal seems to be the main thing you're asking about. I also found a similar previous question. If your circumstances are different enough please let us know. Good luck!